# How do i create a batch file that iterates through the files in a folder and executes another .bat on them?

Tags: batch-file

i have a folder full of .avi files and i want to use ffmpeg to convert them to .mp4 files. I followed an online tutorial to create a batch file that does just this, here is the code:

```
"C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i %1 -sameq -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264 "C:\videos\Series 1\S01E01.mp4"
```

This works fine if i just drag and drop the .avi files onto the createmp4.bat file containing the above code. However i want to be a little bit smarter about this and use another batch file that will iterate through the .avi files in the folder and run createmp4.bat on all of them and copy them to the C:\videos\Series 1\ directory.

I would also like to change the name of the files if possible to S01E01.mp4, S01E02.mp4 and so on if possible.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Oh and just in case you hadn't guessed i am fairly clueless about writing batch files!!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (example):

```
@echo off & setlocal
pushd "X:\My AVI folder"
for %%i in (*.avi) do "C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "%%~fi" -sameq -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264 "C:\videos\Series 1\%%~ni.mp4"
popd
```